# Twig internal server error after filter manipulation

Tags: php, twig, silex

I run into this crazy behaviour from Twig: I have this **long** array of names and surnames (packed into a single string), that looks like this:

```
[0] "Name1 Surname1"
[1] "Name2 Surname2"
      ...
[N] "NameN SurnameN"
```

I want to manipulate this array in a way that each name+surname is displayed in the following way:

```
N. Surname
```

Then the output will be put together with some other data in a table, this is the structure of the said table:

```
...
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead class="header">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Field 1</th>
        <th class="text-center">Field 2</th>
        <th class="text-center">Field 3</th>
        <th class="text-center">Field 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {#
      data is an associative array with 4 keys
    #}
    {% for data in parameters.list %}
      <tr class="text-center">
        <td>...</td>
        {% set new_name = data.nameSurnames|split(' ', 2) %}
        <td><span class="name">{{new_name[0]|first}}. {{new_name[1]}}</span><br /><small>{{data.keyThree|raw}}</small></td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
...
```

The procedure I follow can be seen in the above snippet.
The funny part is that `new_name[1]` generates a 500 Internal Server Error and I can't really understand why.
If inside the for loop I do:

```
{{dump(new_name)}}
```

The output is:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Name1" [1]=> string(8) "Surname1" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Name2" [1]=> string(8) "Surname2" } ... array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "NameN" [1]=> string(8) "SurnameN" }
```

If I do:

```
{{dump(new_name[0])}}
```

The output is:

```
string(5) "Name1" ... string(5) "NameN"
```

But anything involving `new_name[1]`will produce a 500 error even if `dump(new_name)`shows that `new_name[1]` is defined..

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem on [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/) and share the link?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The strange thing is that the same procedure into another page works properly... The only real difference is that on the working page the amount of names and surnames is far lower. But if there was a shortage of memory, I think also `{{dump(new_name)}}` would fail..
However [here](http://twigfiddle.com/v59roo) is a sample.

Comment: Turns out the list of names and surnames was flawed. There were some entries with name only and no surname.
For some obscure reasons, this created a 500 internal server error, but I couldn't replicate it in twigfiddle even if a flawed list was inserted.

In fact, regarding the second argument passed to `split( )`, [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) states: 

_If limit is positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string;_

So I believe it should throw an error, but in my case it doesn't

Comment: check how do you construct the `Twig_Environment`. If  you construct it with `strict_variables`` to true this can be the behaviour. See more options [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options)

Comment: or more simply add an if statement to check if new_name[1] is defined as follow: `{% if new_name[1] is defined %}{{new_name[1]}} {%else%} NO {%endif%}`

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Although this works, I'm still confused why it gave me a 500 error instead of the standard `var is not defined`..
Also, I'm using twig as a silex provider, with standard configuration, so I don't know if it is in strict-mode or not

Comment: Yes, that solved it but it's still unknown why the 500 error

Comment: with silex, you can try to set the strict_mode discussed in precedence in the twig.options key . Check the doc for further info here http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html

Comment: can i post an answer so you can mark the question as solved?

Comment: by default the value is setted as the application debug mode, as described here: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/4422f4296806537925384cf72fb29a6b2c93e49b/src/Silex/Provider/TwigServiceProvider.php#L43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigating the problem, there was same elements without the surname value so the code:

```
{% set new_name = data.nameSurnames|split(' ', 2) %}
<td><span class="name">{{new_name[0]|first}}. {{new_name[1]}}</span><br /><small>{{data.keyThree|raw}}</small></td>
```

Fail without a great explaination on the `{{ new_name[1] }}` instruction.

Surrounding it with an `is defined` control:

```
{% if new_name[1] is defined %}{{new_name[1]}}{%endif%}
```

Solve the problem.

Check in the comment for further reference.

Already open a doubt about the error message (Silex framework)